# Column update - SQL UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, alter-table

I have a column where it stores a reference
the reference is usually 30 alphanumeric values
The column is set as an nvarchar (30).

Id like to update this to nvarchar (5), and update all the values currently stored in this column..

is there a way to do this using update?

Comment: The data would be truncated if it is larger than 5 characters.

Comment: I don't mind the data to be truncated - Just need a way of doing this with an update statement?

Comment: Nope. It has to be an alter table statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First update the table so that you truncate all the column values after the 5th character:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = LEFT(columnname, 5);
```

Note, that this may not work if there are constraints on the column (like a unique constraint or foreign key references).

Then change the data type of the column:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname nvarchar(5);
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8918b5cfd0787f0bdb45cf7202714b14).

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick on SQL Server / MS Access:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

Comment: thanks, however I get an error 'String or binary data would be truncated.
I need to update the entire table as there is data stored in the table

Comment: When you don't care for your data, but want to keep the table (e.g. when you have some configs on it) you can use DELETE FROM tablename; That clears out the whole data in the table. Then you can use the alter above.
If you just want the content of one column to be deleted , you can UPDATE tablename SET column_name = ''; Then the above statements should work.